# Luna and לבנה, two similar ancient words for "moon"

Tags: historical-linguistics

What is the linguistic relationship, if any, between the Latin word luna and the biblical Hebrew word לבנה, which are phonetically similar and both mean "moon"?

Comment: The word לבנה clearly means "moon" in Isaiah 24:23 and 30:26 and in Song of So. 6:10.

Answer (score 8):

### Most likely they're unrelated.

Latin *lūna* "moon" comes from Old Latin *losna* from PIE **lowks-neh₂*, derived from **lewk-* "bright, shining".

Hebrew *l'vaná* "moon" comes from the feminine of *laván* "white". I'm unsure where that goes back to in Proto-Semitic, but it seems to be a native Semitic root because it also appears in Arabic *laban* "milk".

It's not impossible that one influenced the other, but they seem to have unrelated etymologies. Interestingly enough, they both come from a feminine form of an adjective describing the moon.